# Not no sorting on datatables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I'm trying to figure out why the first column is allowing for sorting when I gave the datatables modification to not be sortable. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to get the first table heading to NOT be sortable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#basicTable').DataTable({ 
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ "nosortable" ] }
        ]
    });
});

http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/uwe4mp0d/
```

Comment: Your question seems awkwardly phrased and it's hard to tell what you're trying to do. You might want to look back at making it clearer to the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aTargets should be an array of the column numbers you want the definition to apply to:

http://jsfiddle.net/uwe4mp0d/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#basicTable').DataTable({ 
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 3 ] }
    ]
});
```

});

Comment: Well if you notice it still has a class of sorting_asc on the first TH so it doesn't remove to the sorting feature for that field. Also has that up arrow in it.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're using the latest version, so I've updated the syntax, plus added a default sort to stop it defaulting to the first column: http://jsfiddle.net/uwe4mp0d/2/

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#basicTable').dataTable({ 
        "columnDefs": [
         { 
                "targets": [0, 3],
                "sortable": false
            }
  ],
        "order": [1, "asc"]
    });
});